# How to get selector type using javascript or jquery for use in switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I currently have the following code to find the type of selector and respond appropriately. This is ugly but its the best I have been able to come up with so far to distinguish between input types checkbox, radio, text, and select drop down list. I am hoping there is a way I could do this with a switch statement.

```
if ($(selector).is(':checkbox')){
  //do something
}else{
  if (selector.indexOf("radio") >= 0){
    //do something
  }else{
    if ($(selector).is('input') || $(selector).is('select')) {
       //do something
    }
  }
}
```

one thing I will bring up is that `$(selector).is('input')` is the only way I figured out how to catch `input type="text"` however this would also catch checkboxes so I had to put it at the very bottom.

Comment: Where does this code live, and how does `selector` get populated? I'm guessing there's a better way before you even get this far.

Answer (score 0):

I would use $().attr().

```
if($(selector).attr('type') == 'text')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to detect 'select' or 'checkbox'